# Is it okay to change the loading order of JavaScript files in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In my `application.js.coffee` I define some overarching functions which I use in my other JavaScript files. So far this was no problem, because except in `application.js.coffee` most of the code was wrapped in document ready `$ ->`

Now I am optimizing loading time, for instance running AJAX requests outside of `$ ->` to start the data loading beforehand.

Now I need the functions I have defined, which are of course not available since `application.js.coffee` is loaded at the very end. To solve this I replaced

```
 #= require_tree .
```

with

```
 #= require_self
 #= require_tree .
```

Is this the way to do it, or is that proscribed?

Comment: Just means the code in application.js will come first in the compiled file. As long as it doesn't depend on anything in any other files, should be alright.

Comment: Good, feel free to post this as an answer. I know it's not much, but so is my question, I just wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it's usually done. You'd have to require `application.js.coffee` before requiring your other custom javascript files(which are loaded with require_tree). Make sure though that application.js.coffee's plugin dependencies are loaded before the `require_self`.

For example, if you use jQuery, you'd do it this way in your application.js.coffee

```
#= require jquery
#= require_self
#= require_tree .
```